# Cannot find module 'next/dist/shared/lib/router/utils/is-bot.js' Require stack:

Tags: next.js

error - Error: Cannot find module 'next/dist/shared/lib/router/utils/is-bot.js'
Require stack:

- /home/bastion/Documents/portfolio/portfolio/.next/server/pages/_document.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/next/dist/server/require.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/next/dist/server/next.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/start-server.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/next/dist/cli/next-dev.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/next/dist/lib/commands.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/next/dist/bin/next

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.